# Adding XFS Volume Options in /etc/fstab

Tags: xfs

I need to add the inode64, and nobarrier options to /etc/fstab. Are they valid options to just add in under the fourth column? Looking at the fstab man page it points to the mount manpage for options, but this doesn't have either of them listed (http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As `fstab(5)` says: _For documentation on the available mount options, see `mount(8)`._ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are valid in that location. I was using nobarrier on a server for an XFS file-system for a number of years without issue. And inode64 does show up in newer man-pages.

mount(8)

```
   inode64
          Indicates  that  XFS is allowed to create inodes at any location
          in the filesystem, including those which will  result  in  inode
          numbers  occupying  more  than 32 bits of significance.  This is
          provided for backwards compatibility, but  causes  problems  for
          backup applications that cannot handle large inode numbers.
```

Comment: Awesome, that's all I needed. Testing it now. Thanks!